# How to render all pages of a large size file in left side panel using Java PDF BOx 2.0.2

Tags: java, multithreading, object, pdf, heap-memory

I am trying to use java pdfbox and customize it to render my large size pdf (100 MB ) with 1969 pages using that project.
I have changed the UI as per my requirement .Also the original PDF box doesnt render all the pages in form of images on the left side panel. So I added a separate piece of code to render the same . But doing so , is causing a huge memory leak .I can see usage of 1 gb of memory .

I suppose this is happening because I am trying to load all the pages in the memory in a JButton and then trying to render it .

Below is my piece of code :

```
  private JPanel sidePanel = new JPanel();
  sidePanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
  for (int i = 1; i < numberOfPages + 1; i++) {
    int pageListValue = i - 1;
    JButton pageButton = new JButton();
    JLabel pageNum = new JLabel();
    try {
      BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI((i - 1), 100, ImageType.RGB);
      ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(resize(bim, 140, 190));
      pageButton.setIcon(imageIcon);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    pageNum.setText(Integer.toString(i));
    pageNum.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    pageButton.setBackground(new Color(39, 48, 55));
    pageButton.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10));
    pageNum.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 10, 0));
    pageNum.setFont(new Font("Arial Narrow", Font.BOLD, 14));
    pageNum.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    pageButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    pageButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        showPage(pageListValue);
      }
    });
    sidePanel.add(pageButton);
    sidePanel.add(pageNum);
   pageButton=null;
   pageNum=null;
  }
```

Here , numberOfPages has a value of 1969 , hence the loop runs for 1969 times and loads all the buttons and labels in the memory and then add them to the side panel. 
Is there any way I can do this without loading all the buttons in the memory and hence render them on my viewer at the same time while I am scrolling down the scroll bar.

Why do I need to use multithreading for this?

I need to load 2 pages in the memory at a time and when I scroll down , I need to remove the previous two pages and load the next two.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand it, this isn't a PDFBox question, you are searching for a way to create the ImageIcon objects on demand, i.e. only when becoming visible. (This may help, or at least steer into the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323516/jbutton-not-visible-until-mouseover ) If there isn't an answer, I'd recommend to rewrite the question without PDFBox; the java GUI experts might be driven off by believing this is a PDFbox question.

Comment: I have editted the question,. This is a java question basically I need to add multithreading in this in order to load two pages at a time , and then remove those two and add other two . How can this be achieved in java