# Java-Gui Button Not Showing

Tags: java, user-interface, button

I have looked up some possible answers to my problem and there are only 2 that are relevant out of which I found one being super confusing and the other seems like it is telling me to override the paint method without showing how to do it. I don't know exactly if that is what I need to do in this case. So basically I just started making this program and I am just trying to get the main class working broadly. So basically it is doing everything I want right now as the buttons do work and they print something when I click on them. However, one problem is that when I first run the program, everything shows up except for the player vs computer button until I hover over it. Here is a link to one of two threads I have looked at: [JButton not visible until mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323516/jbutton-not-visible-until-mouseover).
This is a personal project and not a school project for those of you who want to know. Anyway, I did (as you will see) repaint the window and added the buttons to it as I know that is a very common mistake that makes this kind of a problem occur. I tried setting it to visible being true, but to no avail. Here is my code for the main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class SpaceGame implements ActionListener{

    private JFrame window;
    private Sprite background;
    private PlayervsPlayer playervsplayer;
    private PlayervsComputer playervscomputer;
    private JButton pvp;
    private JButton pvc;
    private int win_size=1000;//Window size has to be a minimum of 603 because we are keeping a button width of 200 constant
    private int win_location=50;
    private final int button_width=200;
    private final int button_height=25;
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpaceGame start = new SpaceGame();
        start.makeWindow();
    }

    /**
     * Create the window, containing a single button.
     */
    private void makeWindow()//Remember add instructions later
    {
        window = new JFrame();
        window.setLayout( null );
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        window.setTitle( "Space Shooter!" );
        window.setLocation( win_location, win_location );
        window.setSize( win_size, win_size );
        window.setResizable( false );
        background=new Sprite("space_background.jpg");
        background.setSize(win_size,win_size);
        background.setLocation(0,0);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        window.setVisible( true );
        window.add(background);

        playervsplayer=new PlayervsPlayer();
        playervscomputer=new PlayervsComputer();

        pvp = new JButton();
        pvp.setLocation((int)((win_size-button_width*2)/3),(int)(win_size-(button_width/2)));//x=200,y=900-y stays same for both buttons
        pvp.setSize( button_width, button_height);
        pvp.setText( "Player vs Player" );
        pvp.setBackground(Color.green);
        pvp.addActionListener( this );
        window.add( pvp );

        pvc = new JButton();
        pvc.setLocation(pvp.getX()+(button_width*2),(int)(win_size-(button_width/2)));
        pvc.setSize( button_width, button_height);
        pvc.setText("Player vs Computer");
        pvc.setBackground(Color.green);
        pvc.addActionListener(this);
        window.add(pvc);

        window.repaint();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource()==pvp){
            playervsplayer.testing();
        }
        else if (e.getSource()==pvc){
            playervscomputer.testing_c();
        }

    }


}
```

The reason why I don't just set the window background as the background image is because it only takes a color so I had to set the color and then add the background over the top of that. Then the text for later on and the buttons go over the top of the background image. So any help would be nice and thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Problem #1 `window.setLayout( null );`; Problem #2 `window.setVisible( true );` before the UI content is established, without corresponding `revalidate` and `repaint` calls

Comment: Problem #3 Adding components to the window rather then the `background` component which may affect the z-ordering of the components

Comment: Whoops, totally forgot about the z-ordering thing and actually all I needed to do was address problem #3 which I thought I had solved before but actually all I needed to do was every place where I added a component to the window, I just needed to add  a comma then a 0 to it. So for example, window.add(pvc,0); So should I remove this thread or just wait for you to put up an answer and accept that? I did not even need to address problem #1 and 2.

Comment: You'll find #2 will haunt you randomly and #1 is just a good idea

Comment: Hey BobG. I apologize, my friend @MadProgrammer has a problem with absolute layout for some reason. If you want to use it go ahead, it’ll work if you want it to. However, his comment on #2 is pretty valid, and you might want to look into it.

Comment: So what do you recommend then because when I comment both of those lines of code out, it messes up everything. This screen right now is literally the start screen. When I actually write the code for my playervsplayer and playervscomputer class instead of just printing something, it is going to just put the background again over the top of everything so I won't have to deal with buttons anymore after that.

Comment: @JacobB. That's because it's more fragile the glass and easily broken without any effort - why reinvent a wheel which has so much time and effort put into? And yes, I've spent more then my fair share of time undoing this code of decision in production

Comment: @MadProgrammer absolute layout is great for beginners

Comment: @JacobB. It's a waste of time which generates more issues then it solves when "beginners" should be spending there time learning about how to make reliable and re-usable interfaces which can work across multiple platforms/systems. `static` is also good for beginners, but it fails to teach them appropriate techniques and skills which would provide better (and often simpler) solutions in the long run

Comment: @JacobB. Forgive me for trying to help some learn to fish

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are forgiven.

Comment: Um, so can you respond to my last comment and can both of you stop arguing? I know setlayout might not be the most efficient thing to do, but I I am not that advanced yet.

Comment: This is literally going to be my most complicated code I have written yet as it will have 8 total classes, with 2 of them already written.

Comment: Ok so I guess we are just going to leave it at that then? Not even tell us beginners what we should have done or post an answer code? Starting to wonder if I should just delete this thread as it ain't going to help no one at this current state.